# How to manipulate a map field in a structure with reflect package?

Tags: go, reflection

We have a structure like:

```
type S struct {
    M map[string]bool
}
```

And how can we implement a function like:

```
// this function modify field by name to a new map
func Modify(s *S, name string, val map[string]bool){
  ...
}

func Test() {
    s := S{
        M: map[string]bool{"Hello":true},
    }
    m := map[string]bool{"World":false}
    Modify(&s, "M", m)
}
```

The reflect package support SetInt/SetString/etc, but none SetMap.
Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: No need for reflect package, all the types are known so just set the values directly (at least that's what i'm seeing in this simple example). That is, `Modify` takes the same type as the field you want to set, and you have only one field to set... But to set a value of a non basic type (and basic as well) with the `reflect` package you can use the `Set` method just like you would use `SetInt`/`SetString` for setting `string`/`int` values.

Comment: @mkopriva This is just an example. There are maybe many fields in the struct with different name.

Comment: In that case ignore the first half of that comment and focus only on the second.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you. But `Set` method can't set a `nil` map. Any way to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean it can't set a `nil` map? Is the field `nil`? Is the provided value `nil`? Which is it? Where is your code? What error did you get?

Comment: @mkopriva sorry for confusion. I want to reset `M` field as a `nil` like the structure initialized.

Comment: Check if the passed in value to Modify is `nil` and if so take the field's type, call `reflect.Zero` on it and then set the field to the returned zero value. This is because it is illegal to set a value to an untyped `nil`, just like you can't do something like this: `var mymap = nil`.

Comment: @mkopriva But `s.M = nil` is legal.

Comment: The type in that expression is known from `s.M`, in the `var mymap = nil` expression there is no type declared for `mymap` and it's therefore illegal. Now, of course, you could argue that the `s.M = nil` is a more accurate representation of what you're trying to do with reflection and you would be right, it is, however the `reflect` package has it's own rules as to what you can and can't set, and that behaviour you're seeing is well documented in the package...

Comment: ... and what I was trying to point out with the expression *analogy* in the previous comment is the cause of the problem ("untyped nil"), not that one is the exact same thing as the other.

Comment: ... for example if you want to be even more "close" to the reflection code when constructing the non-reflection example you would have to write `s.M = (interface{})(nil)` which is illegal, but this is still a misleading example since the `interface{}` type is not the problem here. It's that the untyped `nil`, when passed to `reflect.ValueOf` produces an invalid `reflect.Value` which you cannot use in the `Set` method, no matter what's on the left side of Set, not even if it's a value of type `interface{}`.

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you for your patient explanation. So the conclusion is we can't reset a map field to `nil map` with reflect package. In other words, we can't "totally" reset a structure contains map field.

Comment: No, you can use reflection to set the map field to `nil` just like you can without (`s.M = nil`). But you have to produce a "typed `nil`" first. That previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415537/how-to-manipulate-a-map-field-in-a-structure-with-reflect-package?noredirect=1#comment101328494_57415537) explains in steps how to do it, is there anything you didn't understand? Note, the second half of the comment was just trying to point out why you're seeing the error that you're seeing and why you need those extra steps to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I understand now.

Comment: i've updated the existing answer to show how you can do it, you might want to add type checking if you don't want your code to panic if someone calls `Modify(&s, "M", 123)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reflect.Set()`

```
func Modify(s *S, name string, val interface{}) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(val)
    if !rv.IsValid() {
        rv = reflect.Zero(reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem().FieldByName(name).Type())
    }
    reflect.ValueOf(s).Elem().FieldByName(name).Set(rv)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Qrq-_ImYLJ1)

Comment: it works and thank you. But it failed if I try to set a `nil` in the field.